# Fetch results from model in Waterline if property is defined

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I've got a model where not every property is required. I'd like to query the model and return all instances where the property **is** defined.

Here's what I *think* the code should look like, but it doesn't work. Any ideas or links to some detailed documentation?

```
MyModel.find()
.where({
    "propertyThatMayExist" : {
        "!=" : undefined
    }
});
```

Thanks a bunch in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way would be to test against `null`.  The correct operator is `!` or `not`:

```
MyModel.find().where({propertyThatMayExist: {'!': null}}).exec(console.log);
```

This assumes you don't want to sometimes explicitly set the property to `null` for an instance, which would be problematic for some databases anyway (think of MySQL, which defaults most fields to NULL if they aren't filled out).

Comment: MyModel.find().where({'id': {'!': 5}}).exec(console.log); 
This works, but querying against null returns an empty set. I tried this with id as well as a datetime type attribute.

Comment: What database adapter are you using?  And is it really `id` that might be null, or are you just using that as an example?  Depending on your setup, `id` might never be null.

Comment: Using disk currently, will be ending up on mysql. id was just an example.

Comment: This solution works perfectly when the adapter is MySQL, but seems to fail when using "disk".