# sails/waterline where association not exist

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I'm using sails for my latest project, and would like to query a model for items that do not have an association. For example

title collection...

```
[
    {
        id : 1,
        name : "ABC123",
        media : 1
    },
    {
        id : 2,
        name : "DEF456"
    }
]
```

media collection...

```
[        
    {
        id : 1,
        name : "1234.mpg",
        title : 1
    },
    {
        id : 2,
        name : "5678.mpg"
    }
]
```

So, you can see that title 1 is associated (one to one) with media 1, and visa-versa, and that title 2, and media 2 are not associated with anything.

My question is, using the waterline query language, can I query for items that do not have an association, or more simply, do not have a specific key.

edit: Thanks to @jperezov, turns out, it's the sails-disk shortcomings, and when using sails-mongo, the following actually works.....

```
{
    "where" : {
        "media" : null
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `{ "where": { "media": null } }` ?

Comment: I have, but doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Try [the opposite of this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22772742/fetch-results-from-model-in-waterline-if-property-is-defined). Keep in mind that using "disk" instead of a real DB is buggy as all get-out.

Comment: Just tried with an actual MongoDB instance and a test project, and it seems to work!  Looks like it was the sails-disk shortcomings after all. Thank you. If you post as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's simply an issue with Sails-Disk. At the current version (0.10.9 at the time of this writing), Sails-Disk doesn't support all the features of a standard database.

Change your database connection to a standard redis / sql / nosql DB, and your

```
{
    "where" : {
        "media" : null
    }
}
```

statement should work.