# Sails.js - blueprint query by if one-to-many asscoisation exists

Tags: sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

I've asked a very similar question on SO in the past, but I'm struggling with this one.

My previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35320904/sails-waterline-where-association-not-exist) was regards one-to-one blueprint/waterline query, this however is one-to-many.

I have a sails.js app using a Mongo DB. I have two models/collections which have a one-to-many relationship.

Take the following for example, 3 `media` items, one if which has 2 titles associated with it...

```
[
  // media item 1
  {
    "titles": [
      {
        "name": "BOARDWALK1",
        "createdAt": "2016-07-12T12:12:37.946Z",
        "updatedAt": "2016-07-12T21:34:10.879Z",
        "media": "5784debe3ad51e3422887bab",
        "id": "5784deb53ad51e3422887ba8"
      },
      {
        "name": "BOARDWALK3",
        "createdAt": "2016-07-12T12:12:42.980Z",
        "updatedAt": "2016-07-12T20:59:05.054Z",
        "media": "5784debe3ad51e3422887bab",
        "id": "5784deba3ad51e3422887baa"
      }
    ],
    "name": "DEF234.mxf",
    "createdAt": "2016-07-12T12:12:46.490Z",
    "updatedAt": "2016-07-12T12:40:08.328Z",
    "mediaInfo": {
      "blah": 123
    },
    "id": "5784debe3ad51e3422887bab"
  },

  // media item 2
  {
    "titles": [],
    "name": "ABC123.mxf",
    "createdAt": "2016-07-12T12:12:49.448Z",
    "updatedAt": "2016-07-12T12:37:55.757Z",
    "id": "5784dec13ad51e3422887bac"
  },

  // media item 3
  {
    "titles": [],
    "name": "GHR87635.mxf",
    "createdAt": "2016-07-12T21:05:20.716Z",
    "updatedAt": "2016-07-12T21:05:20.716Z",
    "id": "57855b90f2d7713e22cdf17f"
  }
]
```

I'd like to query (using blueprint, i.e. REST calls) for all items without titles associated with them.

To find where an association exists, you can do...

`POST http://localhost:1337/media/find`

```
{
     "where" : {
        "title" : {
            "!" : null
        }
    }
}
```

...but I'm struggling to find a way of querying the opposite, where no association exists, like `WHERE media.titles.length === 0`

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea to check if the array is zero length. However, using the `POST` operation to do a find operation is bad design. In RESTful Sails.js blueprint routes, `POST` should only be used for create actions. `GET` should be used for queries.

You could try using the [* parameter](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/blueprint-api/find-where) to construct a query like the following:

`GET http://localhost:1337/media?titles.length<1`

Since I cannot test your particular API, I am hoping the above works. It may require slight tweaking to get it to work. You may find it helpful to use an app like [Postman](http://getpostman.com) to test query strings.

From an architectural standpoint, you may want to remove the null values, for reference see the [Google JSON styleguide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsoncstyleguide.xml#Empty/Null_Property_Values).

> If a property is optional or has an empty or null value, consider
>   dropping the property from the JSON, unless there's a strong semantic
>   reason for its existence.